# SQL relationship between a primary key column and the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an existing SQL Server database, someone has defined the following:

Table `Customer` has a `CustomerID` column which is also identity. Then they have defined a relationship where `Customer.CustomerID` is primary key and `Customer.CustomerID` is also foreign key. I.e. the relationship points back to the same table and same column.

What is the purpose of this? Seems entirely pointless to me, so I plan to remove this relationship from the DB.

Comment: It could make adding new rows rather tricky.

Comment: Are you sure it has been defined as a key and not as an index?

Comment: I've seen this before.  It is the default when creating a foreign key relationship via the table designer in SSMS.  It happens when you forget to amend the relationship before saving.  There is no reason for a field to have a relationship with itself.

Comment: @destination-data: but why is it allowed at all if there is no reason to have it?

Comment: I don't think it serves any purpose.  I suspect It's only occurs because of bad UI design and the lack of a check within the engine.

Answer (score 1):

The relation is called a **recursive association** or **reflexive relationship**, you will need this type of relationship when you need to present a relationship between two or more elements of the same type.

*For example*: for presenting a relationship between employees, you could create two tables `Employee` and `Manager`. But because the manager is also an employee, you won't need two tables. So we create a recursive association that point for the same entity.

[More about recursive association](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php)

**UPDATE**

Setting a column as PK and FK at the same time could also represent the concept of inheritance.

For example:

```
class Person { 
 int ID; 
 string name; 
} 

class Customer extends Person { 
 String workPlace; 
}
```

That would result the tables Person and Customer as listed below:

```
Person 
------------ 
int id (PK) 
string name 

Employee 
-------------- 
int id (PK, FK) 
string workPlace
```

Comment: True, but OP states that the `CustomerID` FK-column is also the PK-column. In your example that would mean that every `Employee` is it's own `Manager` and that cannot change, so it seems to be pretty pointless. You can't even differentiate both if you have only one column.

Comment: It depends on the **cardinality**, if it's `0..1`, it means that an employee can have a manager (and not must). The `CustomerID` is FK and also PK because it can represent at a time a normal customer, and in another time the relative customer to another customer. You should work with more examples to understand the reason for this relationship.